# Can't set frame background image without frame resizing to fit image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, frame

I can set the background of the main window, and I don't need to worry about the window trying to fit the background image or the image shoving the widgets out of the way.

However when I try to do the same with a frame it becomes a huge mess...

I have tried a few things but everything seams to be related to resizing the image itself and I don't want to warp the image. I want the image to be in the frame and NOT have the frame resize to fit the image.

Is there a way to place the image into the background of the frame without the frame changing in size?

EDIT: Note: The image I am using is large enough to fill the screen so if there is resizing going on by the user the image will cover all the extra space.

So this is how I add a background image to the main window:

```
bgImage=PhotoImage(file="./Colors/bgImage.png")
bgLable = Label(root,image = bgImage)
bgLable.image = bgImage
bgLable.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,rowspan=8)
```

However when I try to do the same thing with a frame it resizes the frame as well:

```
FrameTL = Frame(root, width = 100)
FrameTL.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 20, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+N+S)
TLbg = Label(FrameTL,image = bgImage)
TLbg.image = bgImage
TLbg.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

There were some other things I tried but they would warp the image to fit the window/frame and I do not want to warp the image.

EDIT:

I have found a work around of sorts. Instead of using frames I used .grid for all my widgets except for the widgets I needed to be on my side menu. The side menu widgets were not aliening to the top left of the window so I was trying to use frames to fix the problem (using .place for now). The frames would work but I could not find a way to make frames transparent so I can keep my background from my root window. And that is why I got stuck on trying to a background image to my frame but without the frame resizing to fit the image.

Comment: When I run your first snippet for a background image (the size of my screen) in the main window, it resizes the window.

Comment: My main window has a set starting size and I can adjust it after I open the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to place the image into the background of the frame without the frame changing in size?

Yes. Use `place` with relative coordinates. The following will place the label with your image in the center of the root window, and will not affect any other widgets.

```
some_frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="raised", width=200, height=200)
...
background = tk.Label(some_frame, text="I am in the center", background="pink")
background.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
```

This is one of the few times when I think `place` is superior to using `grid` or `pack`. This is what the official documentation says about `place`:

> Unlike many other geometry managers (such as the packer) the placer does not make any attempt to manipulate the geometry of the master windows or the parents of slave windows (i.e. it does not set their requested sizes). To control the sizes of these windows, make them windows like frames and canvases that provide configuration options for this purpose.

Comment: I don't want the image in the root window. I want it in the frame.

Comment: @SierrMountainTech: then make it a child of the frame.

Comment: `TLbg = Label(FrameTL,image = bgImage)` will place the image in the frame but the frame then resizes to fit the image.

Comment: @SierrMountainTech: no, it won't. That's one of the benefits of `place` -- it doesn't change the size of the containing frame.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one. I would have been looking for a while. I had no idea `.place` would be the solution or that the `.place` does not manipulate any geometry unlike the other options. I am surprised that there are not any other question about this that I could find. Maybe my wording is not accurate for my question.